# Understanding the Ehresmann connection

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections

I am trying to understand the concept of an Ehresmann connection on a fibre bundle $B$.

Am I correct in saying that the connection gives the decomposition of every vector in $TB$ into the sum of a vector in the vertical bundle $VB$ and a vector in the horizontal bundle $HB$ (at the same point in $B$, of course)?

Does the projection onto the vertical bundle not exist until the horizontal bundle is defined, even though the vertical bundle is defined without the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The questions you're asking are on the level of vector spaces, rather than at the level of fiber bundles.

So suppose I have a direct sum decomposition $T = V \oplus H$. This means that there are subspaces, $V$ and $H$ in $T$, such that every vector $t \in T$ has a unique decomposition $t = v+h$, these vectors living in the respective subspaces.
Also at the level of vector spaces, if I have a vector subspace $V \subset T$, there is no obvious way to get a projection map $T \to V$ that's the identity on $V$. But if we have a subspace $H$ with $T = H \oplus V$, then we can write $\text{proj}_V(v+h) = v$. That is to say, *we just need to specify the kernel of the projection to define the projection*. So, conversely, given a projection, we can identify what the horizontal subspace is by saying "Ah! It's the kernel!"

So at the fiber bundle level, you're just doing this pointwise, such that the horizontal subspace *varies smoothly*. That is, the projection (defined above) of any vector field $\text{proj}_V X$ is smooth.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is what I thought. I originally had this question as a point of clarification for my question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499165/) about whether an Ehresmann connection can define a derivative of a section of a fibre bundle, but it was getting long so I split it to a separate question.

Comment: @MattDickau: I'll try and take a look at that later if nobody else has answered it.